# TextView in PageController changes font size arbitrarily

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to use a UIPageViewController for an app walkthrough. When the application starts, I present the first page of the walkthrough, containing a TextView. I scroll to the next screen, which is all good, but when I then scroll back to the first screen, the font size of the text view has changed. Funnily enough, when I scroll to the third of fourth screen, and then back to the first, the text has kept (or rather regained) its previous size.

I tried to use viewWillAppear and viewDidAppeard to change the font size, but you can witness the change of font size, which is ugly and unexpected.

I am running on iOS 9.0.1, but this bug has kept me busy starting in iOS 8.0, which was when I started developing the application.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Cheers

------------- UPDATE : CODE FOR REVIEW : PageViewController ----------

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    childViewController = (TutorialChildViewController *)[self viewControllerAtIndex:1];
    tvController = (TutorialViewControllerTextViewController *)[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tvController];

    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSInteger index = 0;

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[TutorialChildViewController class]]) {
        index = [(TutorialChildViewController *)viewController indexNumber];

    }
    else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[TutorialTextViewController class]]) {
        index = [(TutorialChildViewController *)viewController indexNumber];
    }


    if (index == 0) {       
        return nil;
        }
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}
    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSInteger index = 0;
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[TutorialChildViewController class]]) {
        index = [(TutorialChildViewController *)viewController indexNumber];

    }
    else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[TutorialTextViewController class]]) {
            index = [(TutorialTextViewController *)viewController indexNumber];
    }
         index++;

    if (index == 6) {

        return nil;

    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

    }

    - (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    TutorialImageViewController *viewController = [[TutorialImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialImageViewController" bundle:nil];
    TutorialTextViewController *tvC = [[TutorialTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialTextViewController" bundle:nil];


    switch(index) {

        case 0:
        case 5: {
            tvC.explanatoryText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
            [tvC.explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

            tvC.indexNumber = index;
            return tvC;
        }
            break;


        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4: {
                viewController.preview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
                viewController.explanatoryText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
            [viewController.explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

                viewController.indexNumber = index;
                return viewController;
                }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

---------- CODE : ViewController with the TextView ----------

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

    [self.view addSubview:_explanatoryText];
    switch (_indexNumber) {

        case 0: {
            [_explanatoryText setText:@"...text that resizes ...."];

            break;
        }
            case 5:
            [_explanatoryText setText:@" ... text that resizes..."];

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [_explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [_explanatoryText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0]];

}
```

The cases 1-4 use a different ChildViewController (TutorialImageViewController), the troublesome textview is explanatoryText.

I also tried to use the life cycle methods of the ChildViewController to force the text to stay the same size.

Hope this helps and clarifies things

Comment: so you have a viewcontroller that holds you pageviewcontroller that presents the child viewcontrollers. That textview is on children, which may or may not be retained by pageviewcontroller when you swipe. viewWillAppear - monitors your viewcontroller so you cannot control children like that. you need to force reload of your children. Please provide some code, would be helpful to us.

Comment: Hey Boris, thank you for your reply, code follows

Comment: So I did some digging... apparently if I scroll far enough, it get's released and re-created when I return there. Is there way to force-release it so it will be loaded fresh when I return after scrolling just one page further?

Comment: try adding to viewDidLoad in PageViewController: self.pageController.delegate = self; also add to viewWillAppear in ViewController: [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: also, i do not think you need UITextView alloc etc in viewControllerAtIndex: just indexNumber=index. You are adding it as a subview in your ViewController

Comment: Tried both, that's not it. It still, due to some reason, changes the font =/